# Shorten C string from last occurence of a char?

Tags: c, string

So what I wish to do is cut a string from the last occurence of a char. For e.g

```
input =  "Hellomrchicken"
input char = "c"
output = "cken"
```

Problem is I cannot get the count to work, and because of that i cannot test out the logic. I wish to use a pointer to do so, and theoretically i would test if the Content inside the pointer is == to a null value. I used a while loop here. Any help is appreciated thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *stringcutter(char *s, char ch);
int count( char *s);

void main(){
    char input[100];
    char c;
    printf("Enter a string \n");
    gets(input);
    printf("Enter a char \n");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    stringcutter( *input , c );
    getchar();
    getchar();
    getchar();
}


char *stringcutter(char *s, char ch){
    int count = 0;
    // Count the length of string

            // Count the length of string
while ( check != '\0'){
            count++;
            s++;
            printf("Processed");


    printf("TRANSITION SUCCESSFUL /n");
    printf( "Count = %d /n" , count);


    // Count backwards then print string from last occurence

/*  for (i=count ; i != 0 ; i--){
        if (str[i] == ch)
            *s = *str[i];
        printf ( "Resultant string = %s", *s )
            */
            return 0; 
    }
```

Sorry dont know why the code got cut off halfway

Comment: 1. Use an additional pointer `char * lastOccurence`. 2. As soon as you hit the character, update `lastOccurence`. 3. If `lastOccurence` is still NULL, the character isn't contained in the string. 4. Otherwise `lastOccurence - start` is the length of your new string. Alternatively you can use an additional `int lastOccurence` instead and update it whenever you hit the character => You don't need two loops, just one and a memcpy.

Comment: @Zeta: why copy the string? Just return a pointer to the middle of the original string. Unless you want to change that result string, there is no need to copy it.

Comment: You should repost your stringcutter method, it's ok if it's broken.  It will help us to write an answer you can better relate to.

Comment: Don't declare a public function whose name begins with the three letters `str`, all such names [are reserved.](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html)

Comment: In your function `stringcutter` you check the address of a pointer instead of checking the character which pointer points to. The address of a pointer doesn't change when you increment pointer.

Comment: The code posted should not compile, you are returning an integer `return 0` in `stringcutter` that is declared to return `char *` and you are passing it `*input` which is of type `char` where the function declaration expects `char *`

Comment: @BartFriederichs: I wasn't really awake at this time, I thought he wanted to return the string _up to_ the character. Copy isn't needed at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original post does not make it really clear if you want to define this function from scratch but it exists in `string.h` and it would look something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char input[] = "Hellomrchicken";
    char c = 'c';
    char *p;
    p = strrchr(input, c);
    printf("Last occurence of %c found at %d \n", c, p-input+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("Shortened string: %s\n", p);`. On the other hand your code is going to misbehave since there's no `c` in `This is a sample string` and the result of `strrchr` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

When working with strings in C, we generally use what's known as C strings or `'\0'` terminated strings. These are just continuous sequences of `char`s, terminated with the char `'\0'`, a 0-byte.

Because of this, a way of traversing a string that is idiomatic to C is the following

```
char *my_string = "Hello, world";

char *p = my_string;
while (p != '\0')
{
    /* Do some work */

    p++;
}
```

You can use a loop like this to get a pointer to the last occurrence of a specific character.

```
char *from_last_instance_of(char *input, char c)
{
    char *last_instance_of_c = input;
    while (input != '\0')
    {
        if (*input == c)
            last_instance_of_c = input;

        input++;
    }
    return last_instance_of_c;
}
```

As you see, all of the work is done in place. If you want to copy the string before manipulating it further, use `strcpy` to copy from the location given by the returned pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The `strrchr()` function does this for you.

```
char *output = strrchr(string_to_search, char_to_find);
int output_index = (output == NULL ? ERROR : output - string_to_search);
```

If you want to do it by hand then (in c99 syntax)

```
char *output = NULL;
for(char p = string_to_search; *p; p++)
    if(*p == char_to_find)
        output = p;
```

Comment: You set a char to `NULL`? He wants the string from the position, not the char itself.

Comment: Ok corrected.  Were you the downvoter?  If so I think it would have been more polite for you to just make the edit.

Comment: Ok.  Sorry for the suggestion then.  Thanks for the correction too.

Comment: No problem - I agree that people are too quick to downvote in here :)